# Is there built-in support for handling race conditions?

Tags: stripe-payments

Does the Stripe API have built-in support for handling race conditions?

For example, if a subscription is `past_due` and thus I decide to cancel it, how do I handle the race condition where the invoice gets paid right before the cancellation happens?

I can think of several such race conditions. Is there a standard way to prevent or handle them? Or is the only way to detect them by checking the state after the change is made and make the necessary adjustments if a race condition is detected?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. In the case you described, the Stripe API won't prevent that action as Stripe can't determine what the intended action is. What if you *did* intend to cancel the subscription immediately after a late payment?

Stripe does however use the concept of ["object lock timeouts"](https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits#object-lock-timeouts), where the API will return a 429 error if you try to perform too many operations on the same object, which can result in the race conditions you are trying to guard against.

To safeguard yourself as much as possible, I'd use a mixture of [idempotency keys](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) and [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to ensure the requests performed were always intended.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use the lower level Payment Intent (instead of Subscription and Invoice) and use my own locking mechanisms. There are still a few race conditions but they are much fewer and easier to correct/prevent. The main drawback is that there are fewer built-in features like automatic payment retries.